# C++ Algorithm to switch the order of an array in the following order: [Last, First, Last - 1, First + 1... ]

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, iterator

How would I implement such function using only loops?

I'm breaking my head and I just can't seem to think straight.

This is what I've come up with but It's nothing even remotely close.

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
    for (int n = elements; n > 0; --n)
        a[i] = b[n];
}
```

Comment: In place or can you use temporaries?  Does using the STL count (they use loops underneath).

Comment: Those would be fine, I just wanted to know how a loop algorithm would solve such problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for ( auto it = std::begin( a ); it != std::end( a ); it == std::end( a ) ? it : ++it )
    {
        it = std::rotate( it, std::prev( std::end( a ) ), std::end( a ) );
    }        

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 0 8 1 7 2 6 3 5 4
```

The compiler shall support the C++11 algorithm `std::rotate`.

P.S. I changed the third expression of the loop that it would be correct for sequences with an odd number of elements.

Another approach is to use standard algorithm `std::copy_backward`
Something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

template <class BidirectionalIterator>
void alternate( BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last )
{
    if ( first != last && first != --last )
    {
        while ( first != last )
        {
            auto value = *last;
            std::copy_backward( first, last, std::next( last ) );
            *first++ = value;
            if ( first != last ) ++first;
        }
    }
}    

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    alternate( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) );

    for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
9 0 8 1 7 2 6 3 5 4
```

Comment: @JanDvorak It rotates the sequence moving right the initial element of the rotation.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, it works! ... I verified his corrected answer

Comment: @MSalters It looks so.:)

Comment: Im a little bit disapointed. Most people prefere O(N*N) over O(N). A little test with 1000000 entries tooks 43809 ms. One of the linear solution tooks 6 ms.

Comment: @Tunichtgut Yes a linear solution is more effective than a non-linear. If the speed is very important you should use a linear solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a counter `i` to go from `0` to `len / 2`. and store accordingly.

The pseudo code should look something like this.

```
len = length of array
counter = 0
For i = 0 to (len / 2):
    a[counter++] = b[len - i]
    a[counter++] = b[0 + i]
```

Comment: What if there are an odd number of elements in the original array?

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?... This is simple and uncomplicated if you could use another array... `a` while original is from `b`

```
for (int i = 0, i_even = 1, i_odd = 0; i < elements; i++)
{
     if(i % 2 == 0){
         a[i] = b[elements-i_even];
         ++i_even;
     }
     else {
         a[i] = b[i_odd];
         ++i_odd;
}
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> switched(const vector<int>& b){
    const std::size_t sz = b.size();
    vector<int> a(sz);

    for (int i = 0, i_even = 1, i_odd = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0) {
            a[i] = b[sz-i_even];
            ++i_even;
        }
        else {
            a[i] = b[i_odd];
            ++i_odd;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void print(const vector<int>& v){
    for (auto e: v)
        cout << e << " "; cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> b{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    print(b);
    print(switched(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No. Note that the task is not to reverse the array. Have a look at the order in the question's title...

Comment: @leemes ...Corrected... I have to admit Vlad's answer is more sleek. :-)

Comment: @WhiZTiM  Your solution has a problem when deals with an array. It does not change an array in place.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's the space-time trade off thing... This is the only O(n) solution I could think of {space overhead}. That was why I stated in my answer "..if you could use another array.."

Answer (score 1):

A little solution without **if**

```
std::vector<int> a{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
std::vector<int> b;

b.reserve(a.size());
size_t l = a.size() - 1;

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
{
    b.push_back( a[(i / 2) + ((i + 1) % 2) * (l - i)] );
}

for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << b[i] << "\n";
}
```

It works with integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

In my head this worked :

```
a[] = b[];
len= lenght of a;

for(int i=0; i<len/2; i++)
{
     int j = 0;
     a[j] = b[len-i];
     j++;
     a[j] = b[i];
}
```

Be aware though, this might cause trouble with an odd array lenght.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to work backwards. The element which ends at position i comes from?

```
dest src 
0    0
1    size-1

2    1
3    size-2

4    2
5    size-3
```

So if `dest` is even, `src=dest/2` and if `dest` is odd, `src=size-1-(dest/2)`.

The advantage of this method is that you don't need special code for odd-length inputs.